# ¿ Es buena idea colgar la misma pregunta en 2 sitios de Stack Exchange?

Tags: discusión

Acabo de formular la siguiente [pregunta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462700/how-to-compaire-nested-logit-models-using-anova-in-r) en Cross Validated.

Sin embargo, para maximizar mis opciones a obtener una respuesta me preguntaba si sería buena idea formular la misma pregunta traducida en Stack Overflow en español, aunque realmente considero que la pregunta no es tanto de programación, sino más bien de econometría.

En cualquier caso, si la pregunta fuera exclusivamente de programación ¿es recomendable colgar una misma pregunta en, por ejemplo, Stack Overflow y en Stack Overflow en español?

Comment: Sí, no hay problema.

Comment: Sí responde la segunda parte de mi pregunta. Pero, ¿crees que la pregunta que colgué en Cross Validated sería bien recibida en Stack Overflow y en Stack Overflow en español?

Comment: Es aceptable publicar en distintos sitios si son en distintos idiomas. La misma en inglés en dos sitios diferentes, no. Se intenta que los sitios sean estancos, luego cada pregunta teóricamente solo "cabe" en uno. Si publicas en SO y Cross a la vez, seguro que te cerrarán una cuando se den cuenta

Comment: Finalmente colgué la pregunta también en Stack Overflow en español, pero me la han contestado en Cross Validated ¿Debería auto-contestarme en la pregunta de Stack Overflow en español señalando que he obtenido la respuesta en Cross Validated? Como esta pregunta ha sido etiquetada como duplicada, ¿debería eliminarla?

Comment: Esta pregunta está super bien, no hace falta eliminarla porque proporciona info útil. La que publicaste en SO en español puedes dejarla y, si quieres, publicar una traducción de la respuesta que te dieron en Cross Validated. Yo hice eso en alguna ocasión en que pregunté en ambos sitios a la vez (en mi caso, SO y SOes)